# C++ Handle overflow/underflow when extracting string to scalars

Tags: c++, overflow, text-extraction, scalar, underflow

when extracting data from string to scalars (char, short, int...), how could I easily know if the value I want to get exceeds the type limit?

```
unsigned char          function(void)
{
    std::string        str = "259";
    std::ostringstream os(str);
    unsigned char      scalar; // could also be short, int, float or double

    if (str > /* limit of char */)
    {
        /* throw exception */
    }

    os >> scalar;
    return scalar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the new [C++11 conversion functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) like `std::stoi`. They should throw a `std::out_of_range` exception in such a case. Unfortunately, this won't handle the `char` case directly, but you could first convert to an `int`, then check the range manually.